# Issue while creating an ssis template for reusability

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

I want to create a template `ssis` package to use it many times for my staging process.
I created the package having :

[image]

The next part involves saving and copying the package template developed into a drive location where Visual Studio is installed.

The folder that I need to copy the template to is called `DataTransformationItems` the path of the drive location should be as follow:

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I am not able to find the location mentioned above (this is the only folder I can find):
[image]

Comment: I have this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject\DataTransformationItems`

Comment: Also, please consider package parts or BIML as an alternative to templating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding this path as @Mark Wojciechowicz mentioned in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\ProjectItems\DataTransformationProject\DataTransformationItems

After I closed and re-launched SSDT the package template I added in the path mentioned above will come up as one of the template options for the new item as shown below :

[image]